# How determine when last time usb hard drive was plugged in?

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, time

I have usb hard drive formatted in exFAT which last time was plugged in Windows 7.
Now I'm on OSX, but it's not so important..
- is there way to figure out when it was last plugged in ?

[wikipedia exFat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) page indicates that exFat somehow record access dates
but how properly read it ?

Answer (score 1):

In windows, it is possible to find out the last time some USB device was connected **to that specific PC** by running [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html), one of its columns is the "Last plug/unplug date". Said device doesn't even is required to be connected

Your question is a little unclear, if you want however to know the last time a device was used/plugged in, by pluging said device to a new computer and examining some property, I don't know if this is even possible.